# how to prevent calling next iteration loop without getting callback response from webservice

Tags: javascript

I am calling the webservice in the loop for multple documents one by one.Each transaction will take atleast 4 to 5 secs to complete the transacion.

the problem is even before getting callback response from webservice its going for the next iteration nodeRef document.
how to prevent calling next iteration without getting callback response from webservice ?

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodeRef.length; i++) {
                  var config = {
                             url: "slingshot/doclib/action/checkout/node/" + nodeRef[i],
                             method: "POST",
                             successCallback: this.onActionEditOfflineSuccess,
                             failureCallback: this.onActionEditOfflineFailure,
                             callbackScope: this
                          };
                         this.serviceXhr(config);
        }



        onActionEditOfflineSuccess: function alfresco_services_ActionService__BulkEditOfflineSuccess(response, originalRequestConfig) {
                        console.log("success");

             }

             onActionEditOfflineFailure: function alfresco_services_ActionService__BulkEditOfflineFailure(response, originalRequestConfig) {
                    console.log("fail");

             }
```

Comment: What is `serviceXhr`?

Comment: You there? It wasn't me who voted, but best not to post a question and then [immediately go afk](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive)

Comment: serviceXhr is out of the box method.

Comment: In what environment? It doesn't exist by default in a browser, nor in Node

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
 var index = 0;
 onActionEditOfflineSuccess: function 
 alfresco_services_ActionService__BulkEditOfflineSuccess(response, 
 originalRequestConfig) {
        console.log("success");
        callService(index++);
 }

 onActionEditOfflineFailure: function 
 alfresco_services_ActionService__BulkEditOfflineFailure(response, 
 originalRequestConfig) {
    console.log("fail");
    callService(index++)
 }

 function callService(index){
   if(index < nodeRef.length){
     var config = {
       url: "slingshot/doclib/action/checkout/node/" + nodeRef[i],
       method: "POST",
       successCallback: this.onActionEditOfflineSuccess,
       failureCallback: this.onActionEditOfflineFailure,
       callbackScope: this
     };
     this.serviceXhr(config);
   }
 }

 callService(index);
```